# Converting 1D tensor into a 1D array using Fastai

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pytorch, tensor

I have a question, about hoy to convert a 1D Tensor to a 1D Array, using Fastai.

For example, I have this tensor:

`tensor([2.2097e-05, 2.6679e-04, 4.6098e-05, 5.5458e-01, 4.4509e-01])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming when you say **tensor** you are talking about **Pytorch** and when you say **array** you are talking about **Numpy**.

Then this should do it.

```py
tensor.numpy()
```

Comment: Kindly click on the check mark beside my answer to accept it as the answer. You can also upvote it if you found it useful.